# Problem with ksh namespaces defined inside functions

Tags: ksh, function, namespace

I'm new to `ksh` namespaces. The problem I'm seeing is that if I define a namespace *inside* a function, then variables defined within that namespace clobber the same-named variables outside the namespace *as well as* creating the namespaced variable. However, if I define the namespace *outside* of a function, it behaves as expected.

I'm (stuck with) using

```
# ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

The script below (`testnamespace.sh`) demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

function myfunc1 {
  echo Original
}

function myfunc2 {
  echo Original
}


function mytest {
  echo ""
  echo "In function, before namespace x"
  othervar=1
  echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 1)"
  echo "     othervar = $othervar (expected value: 1)"
  echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Original)"
  namespace x {
    echo ""
    echo "In namespace x defined inside function"
    echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 1)"
    echo "     othervar = $othervar (expected value: 1)"
    echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Original)"
    myvar=2
    othervar=2    
    function myfunc1 {
      echo Modified
    }
    echo ""
    echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 2)"
    echo "     othervar = $othervar (expected value: 2)"
    echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Modified)"
  }
  echo ""
  echo "In function, after namespace x"
  echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 1)"
  echo "     othervar = $othervar (expected value: 1)"
  echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Original)"
  echo "     .x.myvar = ${.x.myvar} (expected value: 2)"
  echo "  .x.othervar = ${.x.othervar} (expected value: 2)"
  echo "   .x.myfunc1 : $(.x.myfunc1) (expected output: Modified)"
}

myvar=1
echo ""
echo "Before function"
echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 1)"
echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Original)"

mytest

echo ""
echo "After function"
echo "        myvar = $myvar (expected value: 1)"
echo "      myfunc1 : $(myfunc1) (expected output: Original)"

thisvar=1
echo ""
echo "Before namespace y"
echo "      thisvar = $thisvar"
echo "      myfunc2 : $(myfunc2) (expected output: Original)"
namespace y {
  echo ""
  echo "In namesapce y"
  echo "      thisvar = $thisvar (expected value: 1)"
  echo "      myfunc2 : $(myfunc2) (expected output: Original)"
  thisvar=2
  function myfunc2 {
    echo Modified
  }
  echo ""
  echo "      thisvar = $thisvar (expected value: 2)"
  echo "      myfunc2 : $(myfunc2) (expected output: Modified)"
}
echo ""
echo "Outside namespace y"
echo "      thisvar = $thisvar (expected value: 1)"
echo "      myfunc2 : $(myfunc2) (expected output: Original)"
echo "   .y.thisvar = ${.y.thisvar} (expected value: 2)"
echo "   .y.myfunc2 : $(.y.myfunc2) (expected output: Modified)"
echo ""
```

Sligtly annotated output from running `testnamespace.sh`:

```
# ./testnamepace.sh

Before function
        myvar = 1 (expected value: 1)
      myfunc1 : Original (expected output: Original)

In function, before namespace x
        myvar = 1 (expected value: 1)
     othervar = 1 (expected value: 1)
      myfunc1 : Original (expected output: Original)

In namespace x defined inside function
        myvar = 1 (expected value: 1)
     othervar = 1 (expected value: 1)
      myfunc1 : Original (expected output: Original)

        myvar = 2 (expected value: 2)
     othervar = 2 (expected value: 2)
      myfunc1 : Modified (expected output: Modified)

In function, after namespace x
        myvar = 2 (expected value: 1)                <<--- Why are these
     othervar = 2 (expected value: 1)                <<--- both clobbered?
      myfunc1 : Original (expected output: Original) <<--- But this is OK!
     .x.myvar = 2 (expected value: 2)
  .x.othervar = 2 (expected value: 2)
   .x.myfunc1 : Modified (expected output: Modified)

After function
        myvar = 2 (expected value: 1)                <<--- Again, clobbered...
      myfunc1 : Original (expected output: Original)

Before namespace y
      thisvar = 1
      myfunc2 : Original (expected output: Original)

In namesapce y
      thisvar = 1 (expected value: 1)
      myfunc2 : Original (expected output: Original)

      thisvar = 2 (expected value: 2)
      myfunc2 : Modified (expected output: Modified)

Outside namespace y
      thisvar = 1 (expected value: 1)
      myfunc2 : Original (expected output: Original)
   .y.thisvar = 2 (expected value: 2)
   .y.myfunc2 : Modified (expected output: Modified)

#
```

As you see, after `namespace x`, the values of `myvar` and `thisvar` (defined globally, and within the function, respectively) have both been overwritten by the values assigned within the namespace, though `myfunc1` is not overwritten.

Is this expected behaviour?

**Note** I am aware of subshells. However, I'm trying to use namespaces because of a memory leak with subshells. The code I'm working with:

- defines a bunch of variables and functions
- enters a loop which,

  - does some stuff
  - calls a function which

    - in a subshell:

      - dots in some variable and function definions (which may have already been defined, and which may also have *different values* to the existing variables and functions)
      - uses those variables and functions
- does more stuff that may require the *original* variable and function definitions

The problem with the subshell approach is that when it exits, we leak what appears to be a quadratically increasing amount of memory (such that after ~1000 iterations of the loop, we've leaked approaching 4GB...)

I've verified that the namespace approach deals with the leak; the problem is that the updated variable definitions are clobbering the existing ones, which causes problems later on.

Any suggestions?!

Comment: FWIW, `ksh -c 'function f { namespace x { a=1; }; typeset -p .x;}; f'` shows the namespace being empty. Compare with `ksh -c 'namespace x { a=1; }; typeset -p .x'`. Could very well be a bug. Those namespaces, types, etc. are experimental features. If you look at the one regression test file for the `namespace` feature in the ksh93 sources, using namespaces inside functions is not tested.

Comment: Interesting, but :-(

If you define a function, it does appear in the namespace, which fits in with my observations above...

`ksh -c 'namespace x { a=1; function b { :; }; }; typeset -p .x'` 
versus
`ksh -c 'function f { namespace x { a=1; function b { :; }; }; typeset -p .x;}; f'`

Comment: FYI, I've raised it at https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/325